# If $F:V\to W$ is a continuous isomorphism, is it a homeomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $F:V\to W$ is a continuous isomorphism of vector spaces, is it a homeomorphism ?

- I tried to prove that $F(U)$ is open when $U$ is open : Let $x\in F(U)$, then $x=f(t)$ for a $t\in U$. Since $U$ is open, there is a neighborhood $\mathcal V(t)\subset U$. I guess that $F(\mathcal V(t))$ is an open include in $F(U)$ but I can't prove it.
- If it's wrong, is the claim true if $V$ and $W$ are supposed to be norm space ? I tried to prove that $F^{-1}$ is continuous at $0$ : Suppose it's not. Then, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ of $V$ that converge to $0$ s.t. $$\lim_{n\to \infty }F^{-1}(x_n)\neq 0.$$
  Let $y_n$ s.t. $x_n=F(y_n)$ (the sequence $(y_n)$ exist and is unique by bijectivity). We have that $\lim_{n\to \infty }F(y_n)=0$.

Either $(y_n)$ is bounded, and there is a subsequence (still denoted $(y_n)$) that converge (to $\ell$) and thus by continuity $F(\ell)=0\implies \ell=0$ (because bijective) and thus it's a contradiction. Either it's unbounded, and thus I don't know.

- By the way, how would look a linear application that is not continuous (on $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ for example).

Comment: What are $V$ and $W$? What kind of isomorphism is $F$? "Isomorphism" is very unspecific.

Comment: @M.Winter: vector spaces.

Comment: Do you assume that $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional?

Comment: @M.Winter: I don't. But let's say they are.

Comment: If they are infinite-dimensional *and* Banach spaces, then the answer is yes by the open mapping theorem. In particular, the answer is yes in the finite-dimensinal case.

Comment: @user352653 This is a crucial question. In finite dimensions a linear map is *always* continuous, but not so in infinite. You can find a lot of information [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Continuity) already, including a discontinuous linear map.

Comment: @M.Winter: thank you for this information. Is it easy to prove ?

Comment: @M.Winter well, he assumes continuous anyway, so completeness to get the OMT going is more important

Comment: @user352653 yes, proving that in the finite-dimensional case any linear map is continuous is not too hard. Maybe try showing that any such map is Lipschitz continuous!:)

Comment: @noctusraid I see, I dropped one of OPs assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V, W$ are Banach spaces, than thanks to the open mapping theorem, a linear continuous surjective map between them is open; so, if it is also injective, it is an omeomorphism. Actually I don't know if this results holds in general for topological vector spaces that are not Banach, but in the proof of the Theorem the completeness is strongly used, so I think the answer is negative.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an infinite dimensional topological vector space $(V, \sigma) $ and let's denote with $\tau$ the weak-topology on V. Then the identity map from $(V, \sigma) $ to $(V, \tau)$ is a continuous isomorphism, but it can't be an homeomorphism since in infinite dimensional cases the strong topology is strictly finer than the weak one.